# Additional attributes in options of Spring's form:select tag

Tags: java, spring, tags

I need to have additional attributes on the option elements which are generated by Springs form:select tag.

An option tag should then look like this:

```
<option value="myValue1" customAttribute="myCustomValue1">Label 1</option>
```

The value of myCustomValue1 comes from the objects that are in the items list which I bound to the form:select tag.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the normal HTML select and render the options using JSTL. Spring's `form:select` is just a shortcut over normal HTML select which correctly maps the value of `path` attribute into a HTML `name` attribute.

Just do a view source on the output of using a `form:select`, copy the code and replace it in your JSP.

Comment: Thanks, but will this keep Springs binding between bean and form?

Comment: If you observe the value of the generated `name` attribute, it has a notation which Spring MVC understands. However, you can also make use of the `spring:bind` tags (around the normal HTML ones) to make sure the view and model are bound.

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring 3.1 you can use dynamic attributes for all spring's tags - see [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-html5).